# Jena leaves mem.FourTupleMap and mem.FourTupleMap.ThreeTupleMap when web application shuts dows

Tags: java, tomcat, jena

Greeting Jena gurus

I wrote a small Jersey (3.0.3) web app loading a model created from a bunch of static files into memory dataset (Jena 4.2.0)

```java
ds = DatasetFactory.createTxnMem();
Model m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RDFS_INF);
```

then, bunch of

```
RDFDataMgr.read(m, f.getAbsolutePath());
```

and finally

```
Reasoner owl = ReasonerRegistry.getOWLReasoner();       
ds.setDefaultModel(ModelFactory.createInfModel(owl, m));
```

The small web app, running in Tomcat 10 basically just query this database and return bits of the dataset content in various formats.  But I have the problem even before I get to the querying part (ie. I start the app and shutdown before querying)

The loading of the dataset (above) happens at `ServletContextListener.contextInitialized` stage and I think I do a proper close at  `contextDestroyed`.  The Dataset stored in a singleton and when the lights go down

```
TDBFactory.release(ds);
ds.close();
```

but, in the logs, I get a list *when I shutdown* the application

```
24-Oct-2021 12:40:23.743 SEVERE [Thread-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [gsip] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal.SuppliedThreadLocal] (value
[java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal@3ddefd3b]) and a value of type [org.apache.jena.sparql.core.mem.FourTupleMap.ThreeTupleMap] (value [org.apache.jena.sparql.core.mem.FourTupleMap$ThreeTupleMap@4f7ca31b]) but failed to remove it
when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
24-Oct-2021 12:40:23.747 SEVERE [Thread-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [gsip] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal.SuppliedThreadLocal] (value
[java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal@3ddefd3b]) and a value of type [org.apache.jena.sparql.core.mem.FourTupleMap.ThreeTupleMap] (value [org.apache.jena.sparql.core.mem.FourTupleMap$ThreeTupleMap@4f7ca31b]) but failed to remove it
when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

note, (not sure it's relevant) there are 2 types:

`org.apache.jena.sparql.core.mem.FourTupleMap.ThreeTupleMap` and `org.apache.jena.sparql.core.mem.FourTupleMap` , always 1 of the former for 2 of the latter.  Just loading the dataset creates 3 `mem.FourTupleMap.ThreeTupleMap` and 6 `mem.FourTupleMap`

The list will grow with more interaction, but seems to top at 99.

I have the same issue inside eclipse (Windows 10, jdk 15) or in docker (using `tomcat:jre11-openjdk-slim-buster`)

Any hints of what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: TDBFactory.release applies to TDB databases, not to the kind retuned by DatasetFactory.createTxnMem() which is called "TIM" ("Transactions In Memory"). ThreadLocal in TIM are removed when transactions end. If any transactions are not completed (whether commit, abort) then it is possible some TheradLocals are left around. Does the app use transactions? (If not, then use the other in-memory dataset implementation returned by DatasetFactory.createGreneral)

Comment: Yep - that fixed the problem.  This app is essentially read-only, therefore I switched to `ds = DatasetFactory.createGeneral();` and that fixed the problem